# Postgresql, syntax error while trying to insert into remote table via dblink

Tags: postgresql, dblink

I have created trigger function that will try to insert data into remote database table like this:

```
db_res := dblink_exec('dbname=test user=test password=test host=localhost port=5432', 'INSERT INTO test (table, action) VALUES (''table'',''action'')');
```

When this trigger launches, it throws me this error:

```
syntax error (at or near: ",")
```

Why this is happening? How simple comma can cause this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`table` is a reserved word in SQL, so using it as a column name will cause this syntax error. If the column is really called `table`, you have to refer to it using the *quoted identifier* `"table"`.

In order to avoid problems like this, it is highly commendable to *not* name objects with reserved keywords. You can find a list of those keywords in [appendix C of the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-keywords-appendix.html).

Comment: Damn it! This Postgresql should be saying that this name is reserved instead of throwing obscure messages!

Comment: Well, there is nothing fundamentally wrong about using an SQL keyword in an SQL statement. Perhaps it would be possible to do better, but a reserved keyword in an impossible makes the parser get lost in the woods.